# why this handleCaptureImage function is not implementing properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

React js code in which I wanted to capture the content of the above div as an image but its not working may be there is some mistake in handleCaptureImage on clicking the button the if statement is not working as it should...
what will be the correct or alternate way to make an div content as an image

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './HomePic.css';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

function HomePic() {
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState(null);
  const [showDiv, setShowDiv] = useState(false);
  const [capturedImage, setCapturedImage] = useState(null);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  const handleImageUpload = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      setImageSrc(e.target.result);
      setShowDiv(true);
    };

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };

  const handleCaptureImage = () => {
    if (divRef.current) {
      html2canvas(divRef.current).then((canvas) => {
        setCapturedImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
      });
    }
  };

  const divStyle = {
    display: 'block',
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
    backgroundImage: imageSrc ? `url(${imageSrc})` : 'none',
  };

  return (
    <div className='HomePic'>
      <input
        type='file'
        accept='image/*'
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        onChange={handleImageUpload}
        ref={inputRef}
      />
      {showDiv && (
        <div className='img' style={divStyle}></div>
      )}
      <div className='buttons'>
        <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.click()}>Upload Your Room Image</button>
        <button onClick={handleCaptureImage}>Capture Image</button>
      </div>
      {capturedImage && <img src={capturedImage} alt='Captured' />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePic;
```

Answer (score 0):

The handleCaptureImage function seems appropriate for capturing the content of the div and converting it to an image using html2canvas. However, the function should be able to capture the content of the div with the class name 'img'. In your code, you're using divRef.current, but it's not clear whether you've assigned the ref attribute to the correct div.

Update the div element where you want to capture the content with the ref attribute:

```
<div className='img' style={divStyle} ref={divRef}></div>
```

This will ensure that the divRef is correctly referencing the div you want to capture.

here's the updated code with the necessary changes

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './HomePic.css';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

function HomePic() {
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState(null);
  const [showDiv, setShowDiv] = useState(false);
  const [capturedImage, setCapturedImage] = useState(null);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  const handleImageUpload = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      setImageSrc(e.target.result);
      setShowDiv(true);
    };

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };

  const handleCaptureImage = () => {
    if (divRef.current) {
      html2canvas(divRef.current).then((canvas) => {
        setCapturedImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
      });
    }
  };

  const divStyle = {
    display: 'block',
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
    backgroundImage: imageSrc ? `url(${imageSrc})` : 'none',
  };

  return (
    <div className='HomePic'>
      <input
        type='file'
        accept='image/*'
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        onChange={handleImageUpload}
        ref={inputRef}
      />
      {showDiv && (
        <div className='img' style={divStyle} ref={divRef}></div>
      )}
      <div className='buttons'>
        <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.click()}>Upload Your Room Image</button>
        <button onClick={handleCaptureImage}>Capture Image</button>
      </div>
      {capturedImage && <img src={capturedImage} alt='Captured' />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePic;
```